# how to log conversation messages into azure sql database in microsoft botframework sdk v4 using c#

Tags: c#, logging, botframework

I created a bot with the Microsoft Boframework C# V4 SDK, and it is working well. Now, I want to store the conversation messages of the bot and users in an Azure SQL database. How can I connect and log these conversation messages in Azure SQL database.

I already tried this with SDK V3. In SDK V3 I created a SqlActivityLogger class and called  it from Global.asax file  and opened a Sql  Connection there. And it is successfully logging conversation messages in to an Azure SQL database. Now How can I do the same thing in SDK V4 using C#.

SqlActivityLogger.cs

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.History;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Robo
{
public class SqlActivityLogger : IActivityLogger
{
    SqlConnection connection;


    public SqlActivityLogger(SqlConnection conn)
    {
        this.connection = conn;
    }
    public async Task LogAsync(IActivity activity)
    {
        string fromId = activity.From.Id;
        string toId = activity.Recipient.Id;
        string message = activity.AsMessageActivity().Text;
       // DateTime DateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;



        string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO RobosensusLog(fromId, toId, message) VALUES (@fromId,@toId,@message)";

        // Passing the fromId, toId, message to the the user chatlog table 
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromId", fromId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toId", toId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", message);
       // command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datetime", DateTime.Now);

        // Insert to Azure sql database
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Debug.WriteLine("Insertion successful of message: " + activity.AsMessageActivity().Text);
    }
}
}
```

Global.asax

```
using Autofac;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Robo
{
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    SqlConnection connection = null;
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //Setting up sql string connection
       SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlbuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        sqlbuilder.DataSource = "Your data source";
        sqlbuilder.UserID = "userid";
        sqlbuilder.Password = "password";
        sqlbuilder.InitialCatalog = "your catalog";

        connection = new SqlConnection(sqlbuilder.ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
        Debug.WriteLine("Connection Success");

       Conversation.UpdateContainer(builder =>
        {
            builder.RegisterType<SqlActivityLogger>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerDependency().WithParameter("conn", connection);
        });

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }

   protected void Application_End()
    {
        connection.Close();
        Debug.WriteLine("Connection to database closed");

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please share what you've tried so far?

Comment: I provided some more details, Please have  a look.

Answer (score 0):

In Bot Builder V4, [ITranscriptLogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.itranscriptlogger) has replaced IActivityLogger.

You can find an Entity Framework implementation here: https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/pull/78 (This was just committed, so it has not been merged yet).

You can create an **ITranscriptLogger** implementation that just uses System.Data.SqlClient, and persist any fields you want from the Activity in [LogActivityAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.itranscriptlogger.logactivityasync)

Once you have an ITranscriptLogger implementation, it can be added to the Mideleware stack in Startup.cs with:

```cs
var myLogger = new MyTranscriptLogger(Configuration.GetSection("BotDataConnectionString").Value);
var transcriptMiddleware = new TranscriptLoggerMiddleware(myLogger);
options.Middleware.Add(transcriptMiddleware);
```

Comment: can you please  share me any project which has this implementation.